# Scikit's Pipeline - how to access the results of a particular stage

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("kmeans", KMeans(n_clusters=50)),
    ("log_reg", LogisticRegression()),
])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And I want to access the `kmeans`'s labels (or any other metric of `Kmeans`). I don't how. I tried `print(kmeans.labels_)` or even `print(pipeline.labels_)`, but this doesn't work, and I get error that the variables are undefined. How can I access results of a particular stage in `pipeline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [latest version (0.21.2) of sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#sklearn-pipeline), you could use `__getitem__` of pipeline to index steps.

```
from sklearn.datasets import samples_generator
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
# generate some data to play with
X, y = samples_generator.make_classification(
    n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, random_state=42)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("kmeans", KMeans(n_clusters=50)),
    ("log_reg", LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')),
])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
pipeline['kmeans'].labels_

# array([ 2, 42, 40, 38, ...])
```

for previous versions, use `pipeline.named_steps['kmeans']`